# No se por que falla con if

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo un problema un poco bastante tonto, resulta que quiero eliminar usuarios y tengo el código que funciona perfectamente, solamente si le quito el if con el que muestro el mensaje si ha sido eliminado o no. En otros apartados no he tenído problema con esto, como al insertar, pero por lo que sea no funciona igual con el delete. ¿Por que ocurre esto?

El código es el siguiente y es el que falla:

```
    session_start();

include("conexion.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$user = $_POST["usuario"];

echo $sql = "DELETE FROM tipo_user WHERE email_user = '$user'";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo ="Usuario eliminado correctamente.";
}else{
    echo ="No se ha podido eliminar el usuario. Comprueba el email introducido.";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

El código que funciona es el siguiente, similar al anterior pero sin el if:

```
    session_start();

include("conexion.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$user = $_POST["usuario"];

echo $sql = "DELETE FROM tipo_user WHERE email_user = '$user'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: sería más claro si indicas claramente el código con el que funciona y el código con el que no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aparentemente el problema lo tienes en la manera de usar el `echo`. Quizás sea ignorancia mía y que estés usando algún **framework** que te permita esa sintaxis, pero la manera normal de usar el `echo` de **PHP** es la siguiente:

```
echo 'Texto a imprimir';
```

O también:

```
echo('Texto a imprimir');
```

Por lo que tu código debería quedar:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
    echo "Usuario eliminado correctamente.";
}else{
    echo "No se ha podido eliminar el usuario. Comprueba el email introducido.";
}
```

Seguramente por consola se te esté arrojando un error **500** por sintaxis erronea.

> FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '=' on line number 3

Comment: Exactamente ese era el error, no se en que estaba pensando para tener puesto el igual, la verdad y lo peor de todo que tampoco me daba cuenta, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 4):

Una vez que ejecutas la SQL con `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` puedes preguntar si hubo filas afectadas.

Prueba este ejemplo:

```
session_start();

include("conexion.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$user = $_POST["usuario"];

echo $sql = "DELETE FROM tipo_user WHERE email_user = '$user'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0){
    echo "Usuario eliminado correctamente.";
}else{
    echo "No se ha podido eliminar el usuario. Comprueba el email introducido.";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**EDIT**

Sobran los `"="` en los `echo`

Comment: Tampoco funciona, gracias por el aporte

Comment: Y sin el if te funciona? Te borra el usuario?

Comment: Sí, por eso no entiendo que pasa

Comment: pero que es lo que te falla si pones el if? que no salen los mensajes? o que no borra en bbdd? o que solo sale un mensaje y el otro no???

Answer (score 3):

agrega $this->conn tal y como te muestro en el codigo intentalo nuevamente gracias.

```
session_start();

include("conexion.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$user = $_POST["usuario"];

echo $sql = "DELETE FROM tipo_user WHERE email_user = '$user'";
if(mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql)){
    echo ="Usuario eliminado correctamente.";
}else{
    echo ="No se ha podido eliminar el usuario. Comprueba el email introducido.";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y sigue sin funcionar, aún así, gracias por el aporte.

Comment: $this->$conn, perdon cambialo por esto.

Comment: Continua igual T,T

Answer (score 3):

cambia a esto: cambie esto `echo = "texto"` a esto `echo "texto"`

```
session_start();

include("conexion.php");

if(!isset($_SESSION["user"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$user = $_POST["usuario"];

echo $sql = "DELETE FROM tipo_user WHERE email_user = '$user'";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "Usuario eliminado correctamente.";
}else{
    echo "No se ha podido eliminar el usuario. Comprueba el email introducido.";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```